# jQuery UI Two Dialog boxes throws Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, types, undefined

```html
<div id="message-form" title="Send Message">
<p class="validateTips">All form fields are required</p>
<form id="send-form" action="" type="POST">
    <label for="to" id="to-label">To:</label>
    <textarea id="to" name="name" class="mention" required></textarea> <br />
    <label for="body" id="body-label">Message:</label><br />
    <textarea name="body" id="body-message"></textarea>
    <div id="success"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="u_id" id="hidden_val"value=""> 
</form>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.view-messages').each(function() {
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>').load($(this).attr('href')).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: $(this).attr('title'),
            width: 500,
            height: 300
        });
        $('.view-button').button().click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });

    $(function() {
        var name = $("#to"),
            message = $("#body-message"),
            allFields = $([]).add(name).add(message);
        $('#message-form').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 450,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Send": function() {
                    $('textarea.mention').mentionsInput('val', function(text) {
                        var value = text;
                        $("#hidden_val").val(value);
                    });
                    var request = $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/post",
                        data: $('#send-form').serialize(),
                        success: function() {
                            $('#success').append("<p id='append'>Message Sent</p>");
                        }
                    });
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    allFields.val("");
                    $('#append').empty().remove();
                }
            },
            close: function() {
                allFields.val("");
                $('#append').empty().remove();

            }
        });

        /**
         *open the dialog box upon clicking
         */
        $("#message-user").button().click(function() {
            $("#message-form").dialog("open");
            return false;
        });

        $("#delete").button().click(function() {
            //
        });

        $("#sent").button().click(function() {

        });


    });
});​
```

The problem is this: I have a button called compose which opens a form into a dialog box and it was working fine before. The crux is I also want my dynamic view message links to open up the conversation between two people into a dialog instead of redirecting to a new full page. The code above works only for opening view messages, and it destroys my compose buttons ability to function. I am stumped by this. The view messages are PHP loaded into the site via db.

Comment: I see no mention of your "compose" button in your html nor you js...

Comment: have you imported the javascript required for jquery dialog.. isnt that part of jquery ui?

Comment: It was an issue where my view message script loaded another version of jQuery. And the code for the button was in a table above.